# Minimum Android SDK version supported by Flurry library

Tags: android, flurry

I want to integrate Flurry into my Android app. My app supports Android 1.5 and above. Does latest Flurry library support the same?

I was unable to find this information on flurry.com. Testing is showing that it is not causing any problems on 1.5, but would like to see any official documentation, if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version (v2.2.5) of Flurry Analytics and AppCircle support Android 1.5.

(disclaimer: I work on the Android SDK at Flurry)

Comment: Maybe that's not important when 1.6 remains on 0.1% of devices, but Flurry Analytics SDK does not work on 1.6 anymore because android.util.Pair works since API level=5:
`W/dalvikvm(  272): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1158: Landroid/util/Pair;.create (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Landroid/util/Pair;
W/dalvikvm(  272): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0022
W/dalvikvm(  272): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAds;.a (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;ZLcom/flurry/android/Flur
ryAdSize;)Ljava/util/List;`

Comment: @smok I no longer work for Flurry, so if this is an issue for you, you should raise this with support@flurry.com.